# How can I measure the output color of a region of SVG?

Tags: css, svg, browser

[Here is a simple codepen](https://codepen.io/javajosh/pen/yxLQVx?editors=1010) that draws a blue square and then a red square on top of it with opacity .5. The overlapped region in the center is purple. How do I measure that color using SVG properties or a JavaScript call? Note: the composite could be arbitrarily complex, involving raster images too, so I'm looking for a colorpicker function, not a computation based on the fill attributes.

```
<svg 
  width=200 height=200 viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  style="float: left; border: 1px solid black">

  <g>
    <rect width=750 height=750 fill=blue transform="" />
    <rect width=750 height=750 fill=red  transform="translate(250,250)" opacity=0.5 />
  </g>

</svg>
```

[image: Blue and red overlapping rectange]

Comment: Copy it to a canvas, measure the canvas colour

Answer (score 0):

One solution, as per the comment above, is to copy into a canvas:

```
function colorPicker(x, y, fn) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image();

  const xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  const svg64 = btoa(xml);
  const b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
  const image64 = b64Start + svg64;

  img.src = image64; 
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    const d = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    const color = `rgba(${d[0]}, ${d[1]}, ${d[2]}, d[3]})`;
    fn(color);
  }
}

const out = document.getElementById('out');
colorPicker(100, 100, color => out.innerHTML = color );
```

I don't like this solution at all; the browser itself has access to the color data, and it's silly we have to jump through all of these hoops, serializing, re-drawing, etc to get at it.

Note that the above code isn't portable because it relies on hardcoded id's for the svg and canvas elements. See the [codepen](https://codepen.io/javajosh/pen/yxLQVx?editors=1010) to see it working.